Ubuntu 24.04.1 no connection after a while
When I turn on my pc my connection works perfectly and it's very fast.
After a while (like a minute or two) whenever I search something it remains stuck and sometimes it reach the page but very slowly, while in other cases it says that it's impossible to reach the server.
Ethernet connection works perfectly, so I presume it's something related to wifi.
I don't know what to do, it's 2 days I'm stuck on this.
Can you help me?
Thanks,
Davide
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlp4s0
   version: 01
   serial: 40:e2:30:d2:fe:33
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=6.8.0-41-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.3.85 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f797ffff memory:f7980000-f798ffff

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2126]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k


For help with wifi you should edit your question and add details about the card and driver you are using.

Okey, I've provided the requested infos. Or at least I hope so. @OrganicMarble
